# Error in Input Buffer

Tags: c

I am running my code and getting a segmentation fault in my Input_buf() even though i don't have a Input_buf function.Now the header where i have declared Input_buf is:

```
#ifndef __GLOBAL_H 
#define __GLOBAL_H
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef ALLOC 
#   define CLASS
#   define I(x) x
#else
#   define CLASS extern
#   define I(x)
#endif
#define MAXINP 2048

CLASS int Verbose   I(=0);
CLASS int No_lines  I(=0);
CLASS int Unix      I(=0);
CLASS int Public    I(=0);
CLASS char *Template    I(="lex.par");
CLASS int Actual_lineno I(=1);
CLASS int Lineno    I(=1);

CLASS char Input_buf[MAXINP];   //line buffer for input
CLASS char *Input_file_name;    //Input file name
CLASS FILE *Ifile;      //Input Stream
CLASS FILE *ofile;      //Output Stream

#endif
```

But i have no such function as Input_buf in any of the .c files i have linked.I used gdb to point out where the segment occurs and it shows Input_buf().But Input_buf() is used in this file first:

```
 PRIVATE head(int suppress_output)

 {
int transparent=0;
if(!suppress_output && Public)
    fputs("#define YYPRIVATE\n\n",Ofile);
if(!No_lines)
    fprintf(Ofile,"#line 1\"%s\"\n",Input_file_name);
while(fgets(Input_buf,MAXINP,Ifile))
{
    ++Actual_lineno;
    if(!transparent)
        strip_comments(&Input_buf);
    if(Verbose>1)
        printf("h%d: %s",Actual_lineno,Input_buf);
    if(Input_buf[0]=='%')
    {
        if(Input_buf[1]=='%')
        {
            if(!suppress_output)
                fputs("\n",Ofile);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Input_buf[1]=='(')
                transparent=1;
            else if(Input_buf[1]==')')
                transparent=0;
            else
                lerror(0,"ignoring illegal %%%c direct ( vv \n",Input_buf[1]);
        }
    }
    else if(transparent || isspace(Input_buf[0]))
    {
        if(!suppress_output)
            fputs(Input_buf,Ofile);
    }
    else
    {
        new_macro(Input_buf);
        if(!suppress_output)
            fputs("\n",Ofile);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with Input_buf in this code

Comment: Ok but then why do i keep getting error in Input_buf()?

Comment: Don't use names starting with double underscore; they're reserved for the system to use for any purpose it likes.  Just because the system headers use names like `__GLOBAL_H` does _not_ mean it is a good idea for you to do the same — in fact, quite the opposite: it is a bad idea for you to do it.

Comment: If you're getting a crash in `Input_buf` when it is a character string, it probably means you're overwriting your stack with a return address that happens to point at `Input_buf`, and then you're trying to execute the data in `Input_buf` as if it is code, which it isn't, so you crash.  There's a web site for such things — hold on…the name will come back to me…oh, yes, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: SO i don't use the __ ?

Comment: maybe show the code for strip_comments

Comment: `Input_file_name` : Are you sure this is set properly? and Are you able to successfully open the file?

Comment: Show the definition of `strip_comments(char **);`